# Is ER model used in database design and software design the same thing?

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, database-design

ER model appears  in both [database design](https://books.google.com/books?id=BcOUCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=database%20system%20concepts&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMhpjMldjbAhXGxFkKHUheAzwQ6AEIMDAB#v=snippet&q=ER&f=false) and [software design](https://books.google.com/books?id=7zbSZ54JG1wC&q=software%20engineering%20ER&dq=software%20engineering%20ER&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFquCqldjbAhWIslkKHRWeBHwQ6AEISzAG).

I was wondering if ER models in both designs are the same concept? If not, what are their differences?

Thanks.

Comment: In my experience, since the 1970's an ER model is independent of database or application design. You can take an ER model and turn it . into a physical data model. Or you can design an object model that represents an ER model.

Comment: "Software design" is a broad term, including database design, which makes your question sound quite nonsensical to me. Do you have any example references  where you found the term ERM in different contexts, where it is not clear if the term means the same thing or not?

Comment: @DocBrown  Thanks. I have updated to some references with context for ER models to be used in the two contexts. I have confusion whether  ER mean the same in the two contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The [Entity-Relation model](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=320434.320440) was at the origin developed with database design in mind.

It is general enough to be used for data modelling and system analysis (already mentioned in Chen's original article), as it offers a conceptual view on the data, not bound by any technical approach.

The ER model tackles however only data.  It was not designed to be model behavior or processing. So if you'd use it in software design, you'd need to complement it with other models such as for example a [dataflow model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram) (to identify the processings) or a function model (e.g. [IDEF0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF0) and alike).

Nowadays however, it's quite common to use [UML](https://www.uml-diagrams.org), which offers a comprehensive and consistent set of modelling techniques that cover both system structure and behavior.  Its [class diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html) can describe almost everything you can describe in an ER diagram.  But it is more precise (you can for example indicate navigation constraints of relations, which you cannot in ER as all the relations there are bidirectional).  And it allows to describe therein the methods that each entity is offering.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean object oriented design as opposed to other software design methodologies.

ER diagrams were developed for data modeling which evolved into object oriented design.  For example, in databases to represent inheritance you can place the parent key as a foreign key in the child.  Analogously, in an object oriented language like C++, the child structure contains a pointer to the parent.  In both cases the relationship is many to one, but the physical implementation is different.